# First iteration of for loop automatically proceeding with scanner input

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a class that takes input from the Scanner class and outputs via the PrintWriter class.  When the program hits the for loop it automatically runs the first iteration without waiting to get input from the user.

It should read Insert item 1:

However it reads Insert Item 1 Insert Item 2.

After the first iteration everything runs fine.

Any help in regards to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
InputSplicer(Scanner input)
{
    this.input = input;
    array = new ArrayList<String>();
}

void splice()
{
    System.out.println("What is the output file destination?");
    outputFile = input.next();
    outputFileFile = new File(outputFile);
    try {
        output = new PrintWriter(outputFileFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("How many items are in the query?");
    lengthOf = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= lengthOf; i++)
    {   
        System.out.println("Insert item " + i);
        //spaces in output are not working for example item 1 cannot equal jason tavano can equal jasontavano

        s = input.nextLine();

        s.trim();

        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
        {
            s = "";

        }
        if(i != lengthOf)
            array.add(s + pipe);
        else
            array.add(s);
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        output.print(array.get(i));
    output.close(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
s = input.nextLine();
```

When you input the number from the `nextInt` it will consume the newLine character from it thus iterating to the second loop in your for loop

**solution:**

consume the newLine character first before going to the loop

**sample:**

```
System.out.println("How many items are in the query?");
lengthOf = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); //will consume the newLine character from the input lengthOf
```

Comment: Thanks bud fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner.nextInt()` does not read the remaining new line character that follows it. Later `Scanner.nextLine()` reads in characters from the stream until a new line character is found. You should use `Scanner.nextLine()` after using `Scanner.nextInt()` to begin read the lines following the number.

Answer (score 1):

The nextInt() method doesn't remove the enter char from the stream, so you should clear the stream after that to clear the remaining of that line.

The simplest way to clear it would be to call a nextLine() before starting the loop